# How do I decrypt data in c# having only the Modulus and Private Exponent (D) Parameters?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I need to decrypt a message encrypted using RSA but I only have the Modulus and the Private Exponent as Base64 strings.

My approach was to create a RSAParameter object and import it using the RSACryptoProvider.ImportParameters method:

```
RSAParameters decryptParameters = new RSAParameters();

// D is the private exponent parameter
decryptParameters.D = Convert.FromBase64String(d);

// n is the Modulus
decryptParameters.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(n);

RSACryptoServiceProvider decrypter = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
try
{
     decrypter.ImportParameters(decryptParameters);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is that I allways get a "Bad Data" CryptographycException.

What am I doing wrong?

Have I to initialize other values in the RSAParameters structure? Which ones? Theoretically, the Private Key used to decrypt messages should be (n, d) being n the Modulus parameter but the implementation seems to need some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you should only need the modulus and private exponent to decrypt. However API wise, because they use an [optimization based on chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29), you **need** the original primes too, and with those primes also you need to precompute  dP,dQ and Qinv.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanted to deploy the part of the code that decrypts the data to a client but I don't want to leave clues in my code on how to encrypt the data. It seems that I'll have to implement a data signing approach instead of encrypting it.